# How to debug spring cloud dataflow deployed app

Tags: spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-dataflow

im using spring cloud data flow local server deployed my stream apps.
i want to using intelliJ remote debug one of my app

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to use `deployer.<myapp>.local.javaOpts=-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=5005` as a deployment property.

I had to put it in properties file and use `--propertiesFile` when deploying the stream in CDF shell, e.g. `stream deploy --name myStream --propertiesFile streamDeploy.properties`. I was not able to pass this property using `--properties` or in CDF web ui.